# Angular: Struggling in component structure

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to create a angular project, but struggle in the component structure.

I want to have a parent component MainComponent

This MainComponent should have two child components

1. TimerComponent which increments the elapsedTime. It will have a start and stop button.
2. GridComponent which displays a table with the corresponding data

All n-seconds the data should be reloaded from the server and has to be displayed in the grid.
Here my problems begin.
Who should be responsible for checking if the n-seconds are reached?
In my opinion the timer has to emit an event to the MainComponent when the n-seconds are reached.

But then?

Which component is responsible for reloading the data? Should the GridComponent be responsible only for displaying the data? Or additionally fetching the data, too? Or should the MainComponent 
fetch the data and delegate it to the GridComponent?

Here are my ideas for the implementation:
Initial the MainComponent will retrieve the event data. Like the name, date and the eventDuration.
The eventDuration will be an @Input():number in the TimerComponent, which signals the Timer, when the event is finished.
The TimerComponent has an @Output():EventEmitter, which will be emitted, when the reloadInterval is reached.
The MainComponent will be notified and will reload the grid data with the event parameter number as a query param (name = elapsedTime).
If the Observable of the Request is resolved, the Grid will be notified for re-rendering the grid rows (I think with @ViewChild?)

Comment: yes, good idea go ahead.  But remember the point that data reloading should be from server or backend to get updated data for every reloading.

Comment: thank you. Indeed, I've created a BackendApi service, which is responsible for loading the data via $http.